# I got a missing dependencies Warning every time I start up Spyder 5.4.3 on conda enviroment, requesting paramiko to be installed

Tags: anaconda, dependencies, conda, spyder, paramiko

[Here is a screenshot of the error message on Spyder startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAlD6.png)

1. I did try `pip install paramiko`, and I get a message that "Requirement already satisfied"
2. I did try `conda update paramiko` and then
   `pip uninstall paramiko pip install pyqt5==5.12 pip install pyqtwebengine==5.12 pip install paramiko==2.4.0`
   which broke my Spyder installation, so I re-installed Spyder and still get the same missing dependencies error message. I was expecting that after re-installation Spyder wouldn't complain about missing dependencies.
3. When I run `import paramiko` I get the following message
   ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _openssl: The specified module could not be found.
   I installed OpenSSL light Win64,run `import paramiko`, shut off and re-started Spyder and still got the same missing dependencies error message.

What gives?

Here is the details of the Spyder version I'm running

- Spyder version: 5.4.3  (conda)
- Python version: 3.8.18 64-bit
- Qt version: 5.15.2
- PyQt5 version: 5.15.7
- Operating System: Windows 10

And here is the info for paramiko after running `conda list`:
paramiko                  2.8.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0